# How to use the auto-generated primary key in the same row postrges

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make an insert statement into a table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE auth(
    id                  UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    role                VARCHAR(64)
);
```

I am using pgcrypto extension to generate uuids. Is it possible to append id to the role field while inserting a row in this table?

I am inserting in this table using

```
insert into auth (role) values ('admin');
```

I want to append the id generated to admin so that the role would look something like admin_12234-3453-3453-345-34534.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an insert trigger to do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION admin_uuid() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.role := NEW.role || NEW.id::text;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;

CREATE TRIGGER set_admin_uuid
BEFORE INSERT ON auth
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE admin_uuid();
```

Comment: Will this work if instead of admin I have any other role string ? I mean I wanted to append for any role I have.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way to achieve this. But postgres allows defining rules on tables and views (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createrule.html). You can create a new rule for insertion which creates the `id` and the `role` as desired.